# Fit a Textbox and a button in DataGrid Cell

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to fit `Textblock` and a button in `DataGrid` Cell. The `Textblock` holds a portion of my text and when I click the button a dialog is display. I general my code looks like the one below

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Message" Width="Auto" MinWidth="60">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientetion="Horrizontal">
                <TextBlock MinWidth="200" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Text}" />
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="90" Margin="1" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I want the Button to be always at righter side of the cell and its width to be fixed. The `TextBlock` needs to be variable, for example when I resize the window, and so the `DataGrid`, the `TextBlock` should stretch also.

[image]

The problem is that, I can not achieve this behaviour / view. The `TextBlock` varies on each `DataGrid` line and in some case the button is not at the righter of the cell.

[image]

I tried to change the `StackPanel` to `Grid` or `DockPanel` but still I can not get the desirable result.

Using `Grid`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Text}" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="1" />
</Grid>
```

Any thoughts to share?

Comment: Can you add an image how it looks and how it should look?

Comment: @Domysee I added some images.

Comment: @Athafoud DockPanel or Grid should certainly work.  Please post the changes you tried and what (new) problem  you saw.  Also make sure your xaml changes were reflected in the output.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez When using `Grid` or `DockPanel` I cannot 'control' the width of the cell. I want the cell to have a minimum width and stretch on user request.  Both on `Grid` and `DockPanel` the column inherits the `TextBlock` and gives to the `DataGrid` a large scroll bar.

Comment: @Athafoud why don't you use a fixed width on the DataGrid column instead? e.g. `Width="60"` instead of `Width="Auto"`. Combined with `MinWidth`, it should give you the behavior you described.  (Although that width doesn't make sense when considering TextBlock min width of 200, and Button width of 90 -- I assume those were just for testing purposes).

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I tried the very same thing couple of minutes ago and as you said gives the described behavior. Thank you for your effort! Can you pls update your answer accordingly, in order to accept it?

Comment: Why dont you make 2 columns instead of 1? This would make the desired effect really easy to achieve

Comment: @Domysee then the button would have it's own column header, which could be sorted, dragged to a different position, etc. -- independent of the text column. And this might be just fine in some cases. In other cases, you might want the button to be part of the same cell. Depends on the use case.

Comment: You're right, didnt think about that.

Comment: @Domysee, having 2 column it will be a very easy solution but as Eren Ersönmez correctly said it depends from the case and it 'does not apply' on mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StackPanel` doesn't really have the concept of aligning to the right. It stacks the elements as close as it can. You can get around this in different ways but in this case, use a `DockPanel` instead:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="90" Margin="1" />
    <TextBlock MinWidth="200" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Text}" />       
</DockPanel>
```

Note that I moved the `TextBlock` to be the last child element of the `DockPanel`. `DockPanel`, after laying out the other child elements, allocates the remaining space to the last child element (unless you specify `LastChildFill=false`). In this case, we want the `TextBlock` to take up the remaining space.

---

UPDATE: based on the comments above, in addition to changing the panel type to a `DockPanel` (or `Grid`), you can use `DataGridTemplateColumn.Width` to a fixed value instead of `Auto`. This would make the column load with the specified with but the user can still modify the column with if  they want to:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Message" Width="60" MinWidth="60">
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd set a static value to the `DataGridTemplateColumn.Width`--it can help with rendering performance.  Set the size on your buttons too, so it doesn't size to fit text.

This works for me (I used the border for visualization purposes):

```
<Window ...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Model}"
                      x:Key="VmItem">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Original}" />
                </Border>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="1" Content="{Binding Encoded}" MinWidth="90" MaxWidth="90"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Message" CellTemplate="{StaticResource VmItem}" Width="300" MinWidth="100"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Proof:

[image]